# Prove $\tan\frac\pi{16}+2\tan\frac\pi8+4=\cot\frac{\pi}{16}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove that $\tan\dfrac{\pi}{16}+2\tan\dfrac{\pi}{8}+4=\cot\dfrac{\pi}{16}$

**My Attempt**
\begin{align}
&\tan\dfrac{\pi}{16}+2\tan\dfrac{\pi}{8}+4=\dfrac{1}{\cot\dfrac{\pi}{16}}+\dfrac{2}{\cot\dfrac{\pi}{8}}+4\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\cot\dfrac{\pi}{16}}+2\dfrac{2\cot\dfrac{\pi}{16}}{\cot^2\dfrac{\pi}{16}-1}+4=\dfrac{\cot^2\dfrac{\pi}{16}-1+4\cot^2\dfrac{\pi}{16}+4\cot^3\dfrac{\pi}{16}-\cot\dfrac{\pi}{16}}{\cot\dfrac{\pi}{16}(\cot^2\dfrac{\pi}{16}-1)}\\
&=
\end{align}

I don't think its going anywhere with my attempt, Is there an easy way to prove this ?

I have checked a similar post [Reducing $\tan\frac{\pi}{16} + 2\tan\frac{\pi}{8}+4$ to $\cot\frac{\pi}{16}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1814092/reducing-tan-frac-pi16-2-tan-frac-pi8-4-to-cot-frac-pi16), but as it was a multiple choice question hope there \d be any direct way to solve this.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305793/find-solutions-of-cot-x-tan-x-4-cot2x-0-for-x-in-0-360

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thanx. but actually i don't want to use that formula

Comment: @ss1729 why not?  $2\cot 2x=\cot x-\tan x$ is what you get by taking reciprocal of the double formula for tan.

Comment: @ss1729, The accepted answer has used that formula only, right?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thats right, and thanx. u are right i think i realise, using that formula is the best way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given $$\tan\dfrac{\pi}{16}+2\tan\dfrac{\pi}{8}+4=\cot\dfrac{\pi}{16}$$

Now $$\cot \theta-\tan\theta=\dfrac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}-\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}=\dfrac{\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}{\sin\theta\cos\theta}=\dfrac{\cos2\theta}{\dfrac12\sin2\theta}=2\cot2\theta$$

Since $\cot\theta-\tan\theta=2\cot2\theta\ \ $ we get

> $$\cot\theta-2\cot2\theta=\tan\theta$$

Now

$\tan\dfrac{\pi}{16}+2\tan\dfrac{\pi}{8}+4=\cot\dfrac{\pi}{16}-2\cot\dfrac{\pi}{8}+2\left(\cot\dfrac{\pi}{8}-2\cot\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)+4$

$$=\cot\dfrac{\pi}{16}-4\cot\dfrac{\pi}{4}+4$$$$=\cot\dfrac{\pi}{16}-4+4$$
$$=\cot\dfrac{\pi}{16}$$

Therefore,

> $$\tan\dfrac{\pi}{16}+2\tan\dfrac{\pi}{8}+4=\cot\dfrac{\pi}{16}$$